# How to Customize a Progress Bar In Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am working on an app in which I want to show a `ProgressBar`, but I want to replace the default Android `ProgressBar`.

So how can I customize the `ProgressBar`?

Do I need some graphics and animation for that?

I read the following post but could not get it to work:

[Custom Progress bar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322740/custom-progress-bar-android)

Comment: Try this custom progress bar is [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Customizing a `ProgressBar` requires defining the attribute or properties for the background and progress of your progress bar.

Create an XML file named `customprogressbar.xml` in your `res->drawable` folder:

**custom_progressbar.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#000001"
                android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#0d1522"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
   </item>

  <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#007A00"
                android:centerColor="#007A00"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now you need to set the `progressDrawable` property in `customprogressbar.xml` (drawable)

You can do this in the XML file or in the Activity (at run time).

Do the following in your XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**At run time do the following**

```
// Get the Drawable custom_progressbar                     
    Drawable draw=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);
// set the drawable as progress drawable
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);
```

Edit: corrected xml layout

Comment: what is res ?? res.getDrawable not found

Comment: @hirengamit res is "Resource". Your error is probably indicating that the file cannot be found. "C:/whereYourProjectFolderIs/res/drawable/customprogressbar.xml" <-- cannot be found.

If it is there, try "clean" your project, it remakes the resource file.

Comment: You may want to check this tutorial out too: http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/ It contains a couple of creative examples on progress bars in Android.

Comment: @Johnson , res stands for Resource. If you replace the line to Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar); it should work.

Comment: Why is it necessary to set the progress drawable at runtime, when it is possible to do it on the xml file?

Comment: @NicolásArias maybe you want to change its appearance, for any possible reason (e.g. changing from green as in "waiting for response" to red as in "waiting for error handling")

Comment: Is it possible to have a different height of the 2 items in the layer-list?

Comment: i had to change "android:progressDrawable" to "android:indeterminateDrawable" for this to work!

Answer (score 42):

In case of complex `ProgressBar` like this,

[image]

use `ClipDrawable`.

> NOTE : I've not used `ProgressBar` here in this example. I've achieved
>   this using [ClipDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) by clipping image with `Animation`.

A `Drawable` that clips another `Drawable` based on this `Drawable`'s current level value. You can control how much the child `Drawable` gets clipped in width and height based on the level, as well as a gravity to control where it is placed in its overall container. `Most often used to implement things like progress bars`, by increasing the drawable's level with `setLevel()`.

> NOTE : The drawable is clipped completely and not visible when the level is 0
>   and fully revealed when the level is 10,000.

I've used this two images to make this `CustomProgressBar`.

*scall.png*

[image: scall.png]

*ballon_progress.png*

[image: ballon_progress.png]

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText etPercent;
private ClipDrawable mImageDrawable;

// a field in your class
private int mLevel = 0;
private int fromLevel = 0;
private int toLevel = 0;

public static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;
public static final int LEVEL_DIFF = 100;
public static final int DELAY = 30;

private Handler mUpHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable animateUpImage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheUpAnimation(fromLevel, toLevel);
    }
};

private Handler mDownHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable animateDownImage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheDownAnimation(fromLevel, toLevel);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etPercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPercent);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(0);
}

private void doTheUpAnimation(int fromLevel, int toLevel) {
    mLevel += LEVEL_DIFF;
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(mLevel);
    if (mLevel <= toLevel) {
        mUpHandler.postDelayed(animateUpImage, DELAY);
    } else {
        mUpHandler.removeCallbacks(animateUpImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;
    }
}

private void doTheDownAnimation(int fromLevel, int toLevel) {
    mLevel -= LEVEL_DIFF;
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(mLevel);
    if (mLevel >= toLevel) {
        mDownHandler.postDelayed(animateDownImage, DELAY);
    } else {
        mDownHandler.removeCallbacks(animateDownImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;
    }
}

public void onClickOk(View v) {
    int temp_level = ((Integer.parseInt(etPercent.getText().toString())) * MAX_LEVEL) / 100;

    if (toLevel == temp_level || temp_level > MAX_LEVEL) {
        return;
    }
    toLevel = (temp_level <= MAX_LEVEL) ? temp_level : toLevel;
    if (toLevel > fromLevel) {
        // cancel previous process first
        mDownHandler.removeCallbacks(animateDownImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;

        mUpHandler.post(animateUpImage);
    } else {
        // cancel previous process first
        mUpHandler.removeCallbacks(animateUpImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;

        mDownHandler.post(animateDownImage);
    }
}
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPercent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:onClick="onClickOk" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/scall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/clip_source" />

</FrameLayout>
```

*clip_source.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ballon_progress"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

In case of complex `HorizontalProgressBar` just change `cliporientation` in *clip_source.xml* like this,

```
android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
```

You can download complete demo from [here](https://github.com/JaydipZala/CustomProgressBar).

Comment: code is really interesting but it gives me nullpointer exception on img object:

Comment: Find Id of the widget, your exception will be solved.

Answer (score 38):

in your xml

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBar" 
        android:layout_margin="5dip" />
```

And in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources> 
        <style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
          <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
          <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
          <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
          <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
        </style>       
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
</resources>
```

And `custom_progress_bar_horizontal` is a xml stored in drawable folder which defines your custom progress bar. For more detail see this [blog](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html).

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 11):

There are two types of progress bars called determinate progress bar (fixed duration) and indeterminate progress bar (unknown duration).

Drawables for both of types of progress bar can be customized by defining drawable as xml resource. You can find more information about progress bar styles and customization at http://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples.

**Customizing fixed or horizontal progress bar :**

Below xml is a drawable resource for horizontal progress bar customization.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#90caf9" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated">
                <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
                <size android:height="20dp" />
                <solid android:color="#b9f6ca" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Customizing indeterminate progress bar**

Below xml is a drawable resource for circular progress bar customization.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:top="16dp"
        android:bottom="16dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="315">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <size
                            android:width="80dp"
                            android:height="80dp" />
                        <stroke
                            android:width="6dp"
                            android:color="#b71c1c" />
                    </shape>
                </rotate>           
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Customizing the color of progressbar namely in case of spinner type needs an xml file and initiating codes in their respective java files.**

Create an xml file and name it as progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".Radio_Activity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use the following code to get the spinner in various expected color.Here we use the hexcode to display spinner in blue color.

```
Progressbar spinner = (ProgressBar) progrees.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#80DAEB"),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Is there any way of set this color filter for the whole app, i mean, in every progressbar, like setting it in styles or sth? thnx

Answer (score 7):

For using custom drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

(add under res/drawable `progress.xml`). `my_drawable` may be xml, png

Then in your layout use

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_circle"
...
/>
```

Comment: This is the best answer I ever have seen. Works like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Creating Custom ProgressBar like hotstar.

1. Add Progress bar on layout file and set the indeterminateDrawable with drawable file.

activity_main.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/player_progressbar"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
    />
```

2. Create new xml file in res\drawable

custom_progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadius="35dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
       <size
           android:height="80dp"
           android:width="80dp" />

       <gradient
            android:centerColor="#80b7b4b2"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#f4eef0"
            android:startColor="#00938c87"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to create customize a progress bar in Android:

1. Initialize and show dialog:

   ```
   MyProgressDialog progressdialog = new MyProgressDialog(getActivity());
   progressdialog.show();
   ```
2. Create method:

   ```
   public class MyProgressDialog extends AlertDialog {
         public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
             super(context);
             getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
         }

         @Override
         public void show() {
             super.show();
             setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress);
         }
   }
   ```
3. Create layout XML:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:clickable="true">

       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

         <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbarr"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/eightfive"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/eightfive"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progresscustombg" />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressbarr"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Please wait"/>
       </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
4. Create shape progresscustombg.xml and put res/drawable:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromDegrees="0"
     android:pivotX="50%"
     android:pivotY="50%"
     android:toDegrees="360" >

       <shape
          android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
          android:shape="ring"
          android:thicknessRatio="20"
          android:useLevel="false" >
           <size
               android:height="@dimen/eightfive"
               android:width="@dimen/eightfive" />

           <gradient
               android:centerY="0.50"
               android:endColor="@color/color_green_icash"
               android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
               android:type="sweep"
               android:useLevel="false" />
       </shape>

   </rotate>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in code, here is a sample:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
pd.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.setTextSize(20);
tv.setText("Waiting...");
pd.setCustomTitle(tv);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.show();
```

Using TextView gives you an option to change color, size, and font of your text. Otherwise you can just call setMessage(), as usual.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:id="@+id/progressBarGallery"/>
```

and `@drawable/loading` is `src\main\res\drawable\loading.gif` file, and its size is 200 by 200