# Android Layout Youtube Like Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image: Youtube Likes Bar]

I'd like to insert a bar like that in the image (YouTube) in my android layout.
Is there any ready-to use widget to achieve that? What would you use?
Two rectangles? A progress bar correctly styled? Can you please provide an example?
Obviously the bar will be dynamic and the red/green balance will be retrieved
over the net.
I'm targeting 7+ API.
Many thanks.

Comment: Use the progress bar for showing the progress.Then for the text use text view.Image for imageview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such control in android. You have to use the custom progress bar.for this u look for this below link

> http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html

also to custom the progress u can refer this link

> [How to Customize a Progress Bar In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)

To show the like and dislike You have to use the imageview.
There is no other way to do this

Answer (score 1):

The likes and dislikes can use a TextView by settings their drawable properties:
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon"

or in code :

```
    myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left,int  top,int  right,int     bottom)
```

the ints are drawable resources. Use 0 if you want nothing there.