# How to implement registration/sign up in android?

Tags: android, registration, progress

I want to setup a user registration which consists of multiple steps. Each step will be highlighted in the form of bars. Dark grey bar will be the steps that are completed and light grey bar will be steps that needs to be completed. Cant seem to think of a way to do this. Please suggest.

We can see this in myfitnesspal sign up. I have highlighted this in red box in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/step1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_active" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/step2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_active" />

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/step3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_active" />

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/step4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_active" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/steptitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventItemTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/symptomstitlebar"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/event_title_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/stepContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/event_tab_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

try a layout like this and define fragments to change the content dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a continous bar you can use a custom progress bar as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893773/2737421).

If you really want the individual segments like in the picture you will probably have to create a 'light' and 'dark' image resource and place a bunch of ImageViews in a horizontal LinearLayout. As you go the next step you will just change the drawable of that ImageView to the 'dark' image resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this library: https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager