# how to make home tab menu like my image

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I want to make tab dynamic which will look like below image.

[image]

If press inn quiz1 then start quiz activity. 
and then when I press Quiz-Results then start that activity.

Comment: Some code samples with what you have done or tried would be welcome.

Comment: You create your own layout for this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754542/how-to-implement-registration-sign-up-in-android/20754742#20754742

Answer (score 1):

1. Within a layout create a horizontal list view to hold the top bar and below that create one Frame layout and use fragments to replace in that views.
2. Use fragment activity to handle this layout
3. and dynamically add items to that list view and set Tag(something) to mention which task it has to be performed when clicked.
4. and based on the tag open respective fragment in that frame layout.

Comment: Ok thanks for this of how can i call dynamically...

Comment: list view is there na . list view item click,get the view item at that position and get the gat. based on the tag replace the fragment

Comment: Do u have any code for this. any demo idea?

Comment: horizontal list view  - http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34
fragment replace - http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/replace-fragment.html