# Remove progress bar background in android progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

How do I remove the grey background and only display the blue progress strip in the progress bar.

[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: That is not what I want. I want the native holo progress bar just without the background.

Comment: you still have to customise  the progress bar. just change the background to white

Comment: One cannot simply change the native views. Make custom or use native.

Comment: I have tried adding `android:background="#ffffff"` and `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to the progress bar but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7808/easy-way-to-change-progressbar-standard-color-scheme-in-mono-for-android

Comment: http://android.okhelp.cz/progressbar-background-and-fore-color-android-sample/

Comment: @RachelGallen all these links defeat my purpose as they do not give me native look. Is there any way where I can get the native look and get rid of the grey background?

Comment: are you using holo light?

Comment: holo-light is different http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already answered a question with a similar requirement:

---

Result:

[image: Result]

To remove it, simply searching for the background by id and trying to hide it doesn't work. To remove the background, I had to create identical drawble of the system version and remove the background item.

TL;DR: Create file `progress_horizontal_holo_no_background_light.xml` and paste this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_secondary_holo_light" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_primary_holo_light" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Copy appropriate .png drawables from `sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/drawable-xxx/` to your project and then in the code you can add:

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_horizontal_holo_no_background_light));
```

or set attribute in the xml file containing the `ProgressBar`

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_no_background_light"
```

Comment: How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: @MauroAlexandro see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252422/818821 but I found I had to do `((LayerDrawable) drawable).setDrawableForLayerId(android.R.id.progress, newDrawable)` because the drawable is a layer list

Answer (score 2):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_timer"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
    android:max="30000"
    android:progressTint="@color/color_primary_blue"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:secondaryProgress="30000"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/background_color"
    android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/background_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_mfa_type"
    tools:progress="15000" />
```

The key is these properties

```
android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/background_color"
android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/background_color"
```