# How should i remove the blank dialog showing behind my progress dialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

[progress dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asRGc.png)

I have researched a lot about it but could not find anything should i use Async task for my progress dialog or is is possible that that the duplicate dialog box is showing due to super.show();.Please refer the image above

Below is my code:

```
private ProgressDialog m_dialog = null;

if (m_dialog == null){
    m_dialog = new Dialog(...); // initiate it the way you need
    m_dialog.show();
} 
else if (!m_dialog.isShowing()){
    m_dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use follow link [Remove progress bar background in android progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233577/remove-progress-bar-background-in-android-progress-bar) 
if it is not use full plese Make the custom Progressbar 
as following make the custom AlertDialog

```
public static AlertDialog getAlertProgress(Activity mActivity)
{

    final AlertDialog alertDialog;
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.process_layout,null,false);

    AVLoadingIndicatorView avLoadingIndicatorView = (AVLoadingIndicatorView)layout.findViewById(R.id.progress_avi);

    avLoadingIndicatorView.show();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);

    builder.setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
return alertDialog;

}
```

or xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
//here i use the libery progress accordint to my project you can use progress bar here
    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress_avi"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:indicatorName="LineScaleIndicator"
    app:indicatorColor="@color/bagintero2"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or you can use it where you want or when you want ..
for using if do

```
    Alertdialog alertdialog = Clasneme.getAlertprogress(activityName.this);
    alertdialog.show;
```

or when you want to dismiss

```
       alertdialog.dismiss;
```

Comment: you can use a progressBar with a text to the right that should be better than trying to remove a background behind a ProgressDialog