# Android - Tinting ProgressBar on pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, android-api-levels

My app's minimum API-level is 19 (KitKat), and contains a layout with a horizontal `ProgressBar`. I'm using `android:progressTint` attribute to tint the bar to a custom color. It works pretty well on Lollipop (API 21) and above, but below (for example on API 19) it doesn't; it shows up in a different color. The reason is that this attribute

> is only used in API level 21 and higher

as Android Studio states.

So I'm wondering what can be a good alternative for tinting the `ProgressBar` on pre-Lollipop devices, too. Can it be made inside the layout file with XML? Or should this be done on a different way?

---

**EDIT #1:** My ProgressBar is used to show concrete values in percents, not for indicating that my layout is loading. I want to make this clear because after trying what Kuldeep Kulkarni wrote below, my bar looked like a material loading indicator (of course on the Lollipop device, not any visible result on KitKat device).

Comment: progressTint is not working for me on Lollipop anyone knows the reason why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions from everyone! :)

The solution which works for me is to create a custom drawable XML file with the `<layer-list>` root element. There, I'm defining two layer items with the native Android IDs `@android:id/background` and `@android:id/progress`. After this, I can define the shapes and color resources I would like to use. This solution is similar to a more popular answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021119/5596869) SO question.

---

Content of my `res/drawable/progressbar.xml` file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">

        <shape>

            <corners android:radius="2dip" /> <!--optional-->

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/gray"
                android:startColor="@color/gray" />

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <clip>

            <shape>

                <corners android:radius="2dip" /> <!--optional-->

                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:endColor="@color/blue"
                    android:startColor="@color/blue" />

            </shape>

        </clip>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Defined as `progressDrawable` for my `ProgressBar` in the layout XML file:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
```

I didn't have a chance to test it below API 19, but on this level and above it works perfectly.

Answer (score 32):

You can wrap with `ProgressBar indeterminateDrawable`  method for `pre-Lollipop`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

     Drawable drawableProgress = DrawableCompat.wrap(progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable());
     DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableProgress, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light));
     progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(drawableProgress));

} else {
    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use it, the code also runs, but no visible results... also see the question's edit.

Comment: You need `setProgressDrawable`

Answer (score 11):

```
progress.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This solution worked for me better than the currently highest rated one.

Comment: This is deprecated now

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
<ProgressBar
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/progressBarBlue" />
```

Then in your `style.xml` define `progressBarBlue`

```
<style name="progressBarWhite" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, try this

```
public static void setSeekbarTint(SeekBar seekbar, int color) {
        PorterDuff.Mode porterDuffMode = PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN;
        if (seekbar.getIndeterminateDrawable() != null)
            seekbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(color, porterDuffMode);

        if (seekbar.getProgressDrawable() != null &&
                seekbar.getProgressDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) seekbar.getProgressDrawable();
            GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background);

            layerDrawable.setColorFilter(color, porterDuffMode);
            seekbar.setProgressDrawable(layerDrawable);
            gradientDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, porterDuffMode);
        } else if (seekbar.getProgressDrawable() != null &&
                seekbar.getProgressDrawable() instanceof ClipDrawable) {
            ClipDrawable clipDrawable = (ClipDrawable) seekbar.getProgressDrawable();
            clipDrawable.setColorFilter(color, porterDuffMode);
            seekbar.setProgressDrawable(clipDrawable);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I hope this will help you.
Try this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="#F00"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in" />
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as I would like to - the `indeterminateTint` attribute uses app's primary color, which differs from the color I want to use; it works also on API 21 and above.

Comment: This is not pre-Lollipop compatible as it is asked for.