# How to use a PSD in Android?

Tags: android, psd

I have a psd gui layout of a progress bar. I want to slice it up and use it in android app. The problem is , unlike a button , how does one add dynamic elements to the static psd layers like progress and movement to the bar .

Comment: Nooooo... **you can't use psd files**, sorry. You have to convert them to **png** s. Dynamic elements (such as ProgressBars) can be created by saving some layers as 9 patches (Google for them) and some as layer lists (with an element which takes advantage of the useLevel attribute - also Google on this)

Comment: I did mention "slice" psd layers in the sense that they would be sliced and made into pngs(This is quite understandable i guess) . My question however is how to use these sliced up "pngs" in the progress bar. I recommend you guys read the question properly before jumping on to find whats wrong with the question.

Comment: No. You never talked about PNGs. You talked about PSDs. Don't give for granted that everyone has your graphic designer skills and terminology. Your question contains some issues. Anyway I recommend you to read my comment, which actually answers your question, specially this part: `layer lists (with an element which takes advantage of the useLevel attribute - also Google on this)`

Comment: I said slice psd s .Its not a terminology its common sense..well never mind about that... Anyway I know how to use layer lists.But The part of adding images to layer lists is what am asking here as a question.

Comment: "slice psd" is not "common sense". It's **your** logic.

Comment: oh well.thank you for your "VALUABLE" inputs..very constructive

Comment: Your sarcasm is really out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to export your PSD file to a PNG or similar format and put it in your `drawable` folder.
Do the following in your XML:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"         
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

At run time do the following

```
// Get the Drawable custom_progressbar                     
Drawable draw=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);
// set the drawable as progress drawable
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw)
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893773/1121804) answer

Comment: I got this working,because this link just uses color (see start color and end color inside the clip) .BUt i want to use specific pngs for the progress and backgorund so that i get an effect like so..http://freebiesbug.com/psd-freebies/circle-progress-bar/ .  As u can see ,the link itself is a psd ..so where do I add the progress image part in the xml

Comment: Yes ,i had seen the link you mentioned earlier. It however gives no way to set a glossy image to the progress bar and rather uses a start and end color.

Comment: Yeah this works, if you play around with it...so probably selecting as the correct answer...