# Android ProgressBar timer countdown

Tags: android, timer, progress-bar

I'm working on quiz for Android and I want a limited time to answer every question. So I want to display a ProgressBar  like below UI
 [image]
that show the like timer . And when it reaches zero I want to do some stuff. I have the quiz and everything working, I just want to add the ProgressBar.

I tried to draw using paint but not success, please let me know how can i got solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some of the library for progress wheel. Hope for help.
[Progress Wheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)
[Circle Progress](https://github.com/487qq/CircleProgress)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you set custom parts of progress bar in corresponding layout XML file. See [How to Customize a Progress Bar In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)