# Progress bar (circle) not rotating in Android

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen, android-progressbar

I am using Progress bar (Circle) while my data is loading from database in splash screen. I used the Progress bar in xml using its tags... but in activity it is not rotating... Suggest help..what's wrong with it?

```
xml:



          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/splash" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Loading data..."
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

           <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    Java: 

    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
        static String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemDB";
        static DBACESS mDbAccess = null;
        public static SQLiteDatabase mDB;
        public static ListItems objitem;
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 100;
        private PackageManager packageManager = null;
        static DataEntryClass data = new DataEntryClass();
        static List<ItemClass> item_table;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
            // ////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////
            CheckConnectionState(getApplicationContext());
            packageManager = getPackageManager();

            if (objitem == null)
                objitem = new ListItems(getApplicationContext(), mDB);

            if (!objitem.ItemsExist(mDB))
                try {
                    data.addItems(getApplicationContext());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    data.getNewUpdates(getApplicationContext(), packageManager);
                    item_table = new ArrayList<ItemClass>();
                    item_table = objitem.LoadItems(mDB);

                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }



        public static void CheckConnectionState(Context ct) {
            try {

                if (mDB == null || !mDB.isOpen()) {
                    DBACESS.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
                    mDbAccess = new DBACESS(ct);
                    mDB = mDbAccess.getReadableDatabase();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

custom_bar.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:drawable="@drawable/menu" >
</rotate>
```

Comment: post your relevant code.

Comment: You have to set an rotating animation to that progress bar programatically inside activity.

Comment: How are you loading your data from database? If you do that work in your UI thread then it is possible that your UI is stuck until the data is loaded. If that is the case then you should use some background data loading mechanism such as AsyncTasks to load your data in a background thread

Comment: @dishan you are right...I solved it as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for rotating image you can use custom_progress_bar.xml inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:drawable="@drawable/gif_loader_img1" >
</rotate>
```

set up drawable to progressbar

```
   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"/>
```

Comment: you need to create custom_progress_bar.xml inside the drawable folder after that you need to set this custom_progress_bar.xml into the progressba  like my example..

Comment: I do it. but same problem.

Comment: Work fine on style ```?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge```. I dont need ```android:indeterminate="true"```

Comment: Also works with `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse`, but it is better to create your's style or use `progress_medium_holo.xml` from Android resources.

Comment: What is @drawable/gif_loader_img1

Answer (score 14):

This question is old, however there is another consideration. The solution was pretty easy and but pretty hard to find the issue for developer devices.

Just make sure, that your animations are **active** in your developer options. Activate these options:

```
Window animation scale: Animation scale 1x
Transition animation scale: Animation scale 1x
Animator duration scale: Animation scale 1x
```

[image: Developer options]

Answer (score 2):

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loader4_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
```

Create a drawable xml **loader4_progress**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080"
    />
```

For more details please check this 
http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html [How to Customize a Progress Bar In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)

Comment: What is @drawable/spinner