# How can I create cycle bar as like below in android

Tags: android

progressbar example in android application.
How can I create cycle bar as like below in android.

[image: Link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something similar was answered here: 
[How to Customize a Progress Bar In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)
and you can find more styles here: 
[Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76)