# is it possible to make custom progress bar with our own primary and secondary images?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to make custom progress bar with my own image. I don't know how to make such progress bar.

Is there any one having knowledge about the custom progress bar ?

Custom progress bar means custom primary and secondary progress bar.

Please help me.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before you can find many tutorials on google http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/android-s-progress-bars.html

Comment: @Dipu thanx for your reply,  is it possible in these example to use our own image as progress bar view.?

Comment: Ya it is possible for that you can refere below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android.

Comment: It's possible @AmbitiousPerson follow the url provided by Kinjal

Comment: Let me check, i will tell you soon @Kinjal

Comment: Add some sentance in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can create progress.xml drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background"
android:drawable="@drawable/circular_background" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
android:drawable="@drawable/circular_background" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
android:drawable="@drawable/circular_progress" />
</layer-list>
```

And set this progress.xml to Progressbar using following attribute

```
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
```

And create circular_background and circular_progress as per your requirement

Comment: i don't know why but when i used your code my background image is appear again and again.