# Progress bar with background

Tags: android

I want add background drawable to the progress bar. So, i use android:background for background and android:progressDrawable for the progress drawable and when I add those resources, it looks wierd because progress drawable looks smaller than the background and I want it to be "fitted" with background - the same size as the background. I use classic HDPI, XHDPI, etc. icons for background. I just want that progress view and background have the same size. Has anyone else tried to add background to a progress view?

This is the ProgressBar

```
   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_message_cancel"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

and circular_progress_bar:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="270"
android:toDegrees="270" >

<shape
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="true" >

    <gradient   
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/gray"
        android:startColor="@color/gray"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: please, show so code so we can check your implementation. SO info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893773/3922207