# How can I represent information about motor speed in GUI?

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics, android-canvas

I need to show to the user the speed of my robot's motors.
I thought about something like that:
[image]

How can I achieve this in Android? Should I use Canvas? Or maybe you can point out a better way to represent these motors' speeds?

Comment: Does this pic describe the exact UI your users want to see? If this is the case, use a simple ProgressBar. If you want more, then create your own Custom view for more control.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `ProgressBar` with a custom layout.

You can then update the progress using `ProgressBar.setProgress` and customizing the style is well documented.

Here is a relevant thread describing exactly how to customize it ~ [How To Customize a Progress Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)