# Can't change colorAccent from my application's theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I've been trying to change the color of the progressBar, and i've noticed it's using the accentColor (which is Blue in my case) and i've been trying to change it without luck.

Am I missing something?

This is in my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverFlowItem</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

This is my element in the layout.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar01"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

My activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: What do you mean by `without luck` what have you tried so far? any results of how it's not working? because you have `"colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark` which the color comes from `ColorPrimaryDark`

Comment: Yes, that is dark red, `<color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#DD2C00</color>`

Comment: Thank you :) you said: **which is Blue in my case** so the AccentColor should be `#DD2C00`. but this is not blue right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark), Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change accent color for one specific view you need to create style own style and set it to the view using `android:theme` attribute.

UPDATED

```
<style name="CustomProgressBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryCutom</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkCustom</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentCustom</item>
</style>


<ProgressBar
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:theme="@style/CustomProgressBarTheme"
android:id="@+id/progressBar01"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `colorAccent` with that color, you will need to change the `ProgressBar`'s color with this:

```
android:progressBackgroundTint="#a31212" // your color
```

**As [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) says:**

> Tint to apply to the progress indicator background.

Finally:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar01"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="#a31212" />
```

Comment: Then what is it? -> `I've been trying to change the color of the progressBar`

Comment: @Gazta - Could you please be clear? You've been trying to change `AccentColor` or this `ProgressBar`? it's working with the above code, Interesting..

Comment: How about the proof?: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0igkayxdf3c02e4/Capture.PNG?dl=0 :)

Comment: Like i guessed, it is not visible on Android Studio's Preview, but it is working on emulator.goodluck

Comment: What are the versions? because it should work only on +21 apis

Comment: So it should work on `5.0.1` and as you said, it's working on emulator.otherwise, you will need to change the color with a custom style like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android and still i'm trying to underestand what was the question about!

Comment: I know, but you said: `Can't change colorAccent from my application's theme` Actually the question has a problem and it's not clear what you've tried and what you exactly trying to achieve, that's why i said that.and about that Emulator and real device, perhaps it's a fault and maybe you want to contact with the developer or asking a question or opening an issue on code.google.