# Android loading progress bar with custom image and progress indicator

Tags: android, android-animation, android-loader

Apologies if this seem trivial.

I have been working on my first android app and would like advise on best way to implement a loading/splash screen attached.

My designer came up with is loading/splash screen and I am not sure how to implement this.

1. Do I ask designer to create a .gif image I can just play or
2. Do I code this in app in such as way that, the progress bar and bike
   moves from left to right and on completion of a task (remote async task), I manually push to 100% and the image to far right indicating completion.

Please note that the bike starts from left and continues to the right with progress indicator and %.

Is option 2 even possible and if yes, could you please point me to any resource I can use as a guide.

[image: loading startup image]

Thanks

Comment: do u search in so? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: Can you provide your solution for the same. As I would like to know the solution for the same.

Answer (score 4):

Generally a `ProgressBar` is used for purposes like this but I think, you should use a [Seekbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) cuz of the biker you've in your image. You can achieve this by customising it using different drawables.

Here are some helpful tutorials to help you do that :

- [Custom seekbar example](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-custom-seekbar-example.html)
- [Create custom seekbar in android](http://www.android-examples.com/create-custom-seekbar-in-android-example-tutorial/)

**Or**

You can obviously use a custom ProgressBar as described here :

- [Android progress bars](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-s-progress-bars.html)
- [Customize a progress bar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)

Comment: I am finding the seekbar helpful, Will let you know how it goes. Thanks