# Customize android ProgressBar, progress displayed as bars

Tags: android, progress-bar, customization

I am trying to customize `ProgressBar`'s design in Android. I know how to change the color of the `ProgressBar` and everything, but what I do not get is how can I create `ProgressBar` look like one of those old ones in windows.

This is the sketch:

[image]

So, basically my question is how should I customize my ProgressBar to achieve this result?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30231742/6950238)

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressBar` is a very customizable `View`, I suggest you look at the `progressDrawable` property.
You can have a look at this example and that can help you understand what you need to do:
http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-s-progress-bars.html