# How to set an image button ( circle ) inside a circular progress bar

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm new to XML language and have no clue on how to put and `ImageButton` inside a circular `progress bar` and also have no clue if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you want to customize ProgressBar you need to set `Style` and `android:progressDrawable`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then you can create `Layer-List` Drawable or any other drawable.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#000001"
                android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#0d1522"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
   </item>

  <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#007A00"
                android:centerColor="#007A00"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it