# Customize horizontal progress bar style in android

Tags: android, visual-studio, progress-bar

Hello to all programmers. I try to create custom progress bar in android app.  It have to look like

[image: Custom progress bar]

Is it possible to do that sort of PB, and if it yes, then how?

I'll be appreciated for all kind of help.

Comment: Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android) it will helps:)hope this helps.:)

Comment: To @PratikMohanraoGondil Yes that's help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own custom progress bar.

[http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/01/android-custom-horizontal-progress-bar.html](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-progressbar-for-android.html)

It's not perfect, but you will get an idea.

[image]

Or try this plugin [SmoothProgressBar](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)

Comment: There are only description in first link. No project on google code

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [Pratik Mohanrao Gondil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7349963/pratik-mohanrao-gondil) I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android) with some changes for VS XAMARIM

The part of Main.axml

```
<Button
  android:text="Button"
  android:id="@+id/acceptPhoneButton"
  android:minHeight="35dp"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/progressImage"
    android:src="@drawable/clip_source"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_row_bg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The clip_source.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_row"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

The MainActivity code

```
using System.Timers;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
Timer _timer;
object _lock = new object();
bool phoneStatusFlag;
ImageView progressImage;
ClipDrawable mImageDrawable;
Button acceptPhoneButton;
private int mLevel = 0;
static int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;
static int LEVEL_DIFF = MAX_LEVEL/8;
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate (bundle);
  SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
  acceptPhoneButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.acceptPhoneButton);
  progressImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.progressImage);
  phoneStatusFlag = false;
  mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable)progressImage.Drawable;
  mImageDrawable.SetLevel(0);
  acceptPhoneButton.Click += acceptPhone;
}
private void acceptPhone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  acceptPhoneButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
  progressImage.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
  _timer = new Timer();
  _timer.Enabled = true;
  _timer.Interval = 1000;
  _timer.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
  mImageDrawable.SetLevel(0);
}
private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  RunOnUiThread(() =>
  {
    mLevel += LEVEL_DIFF;
    mImageDrawable.SetLevel(mLevel);
    CheckProgress(mImageDrawable.Level);
  });
}
private void CheckProgress(int progress)
{
  lock (_lock)
  {
    if (!phoneStatusFlag)
    {
      if (progress > MAX_LEVEL)
      {
        mLevel = 0;
        mImageDrawable.SetLevel(mLevel);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      mImageDrawable.SetLevel(0);
      _timer.Close();
    }
  }
}
```