# Increase animation speed when using Clipdrawable in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, progress-bar

From this thread: [How to Customize a Progress Bar In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android)

I made my own progress bar using ClipDrawAble animation and it works perfecty, and the code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etPercent;
private ClipDrawable mImageDrawable;

private Button fly_to_50;

// a field in your class
private int mLevel = 0;
private int fromLevel = 0;
private int toLevel = 0;

//public static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;

public static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;
public static final int LEVEL_DIFF = 100;
public static final int DELAY = 0;
public static final int START_AT_50 = 50;




private Handler mUpHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable animateUpImage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheUpAnimation(fromLevel, toLevel);
    }
};

private Handler mDownHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable animateDownImage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheDownAnimation(fromLevel, toLevel);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    etPercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPercent);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(0);
}





private void doTheUpAnimation(int fromLevel, int toLevel) {
    mLevel += LEVEL_DIFF;
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(mLevel);
    if (mLevel <= toLevel) {
        mUpHandler.postDelayed(animateUpImage, DELAY);

    } else {
        mUpHandler.removeCallbacks(animateUpImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;
    }
}



private void doTheDownAnimation(int fromLevel, int toLevel) {
    mLevel -= LEVEL_DIFF;
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(mLevel);
    if (mLevel >= toLevel) {
        mDownHandler.postDelayed(animateDownImage, DELAY);


    } else {
        mDownHandler.removeCallbacks(animateDownImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;
    }
}

public void onClick50(View v){
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(START_AT_50);

}

public void onClickOk(View v) {
    //int temp_level = ((Integer.parseInt(etPercent.getText().toString())) * MAX_LEVEL) / 100;
    int temp_level = ((Integer.parseInt(etPercent.getText().toString())) * MAX_LEVEL) / 100;

    if (toLevel == temp_level || temp_level > MAX_LEVEL) {
        return;
    }
    toLevel = (temp_level <= MAX_LEVEL) ? temp_level : toLevel;
    if (toLevel > fromLevel) {
        // cancel previous process first
        mDownHandler.removeCallbacks(animateDownImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;

        mUpHandler.post(animateUpImage);
    } else {
        // cancel previous process first
        mUpHandler.removeCallbacks(animateUpImage);
        MainActivity.this.fromLevel = toLevel;

        mDownHandler.post(animateDownImage);
    }
}
```

}

I set my "DELAY" variable to be 0, which increased the speed a little bit, however, I am not completely satisfied with the speed and would love to increase the speed more. Is this somehow possible? And if not, is there a chance that I can create a normal progress(would work here for sure), but using my own custom edited images?

Appreciate all answers!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I changed this line:

```
mDownHandler.postDelayed(animateDownImage, DELAY);
```

with this:

```
mDownHandler.postAtTime(animateDownImage,DELAY);
```