# Horizontal progress bar with oblique segment custom view Android

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-custom-view

I would like to know how to implement the segment that needs to look like parallelograms but not rectangles. Here[image]

Comment: could this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: Thanks but not that much